# StartX failing to run:- Arch linux openbox

Tags: linux, archlinux, xorg

I am a linux noob trying to setup openbox on an arch linux base. I am trying to get it as lightweight as possible in terms of resources used.

My final plan is to use openbox, with tint1 and conky.

however I am having an issue getting openbox to start. I have followed numerous guides and am struggling to figure out the problem.

I have so far installed the following (and done this config)

openbox (installed default option with the extras asked for)
create ~/.conifg/openbox
copied, rc.xml, menu.xml, autostart, environment to the above location

pyxdg
xorg-xinit
xorg-server

this didn't work so I the installed the full

xorg

still nothing, although when I try to run startx the screen goes black for a second as though it is trying, but then goes back to text mode saying it has failed.

I have had a look at the attached log file, but I don't know enough to be able to interpret it properly.

log file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r76fowkooi822y9/Xorg.log?dl=0

I would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> still nothing, although when I try to run startx the screen goes black for a second as though it is trying, but then goes back to text mode saying it has failed.

what is it saying?

There is only one error: `(EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied`, try starting your environment with the same configuration as root - just to see if it works. Maybe its a problem related to rootless X.

Have you configured/checked your installation (xserver, graphics driver, xinit config) using the following guides?

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xinitrc

Try to start a minimal X (As described in the xinitrc article) to see if your xserver and graphics driver is working correctly.